# Prefix the tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I don't Know if it's symfony or doctrine issue
I would like to prefix my tables, I managed to prefix all of them but now I want to do it for some of them, So I tried this way. Nothind happen, no prefix

in my eventListener in App\Event:`

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Event;
 
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
 
 
 
class TablePrefixEventListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $config;
 
    /**
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function setConfig(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
 
    /**
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
 
        if (!$classMetadata->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable() || $classMetadata->getName() === $classMetadata->rootEntityName) {
            $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable([
                'name' => $this->getPrefix($classMetadata->getName(), $classMetadata->getTableName()) . $classMetadata->getTableName()
            ]);
        }
 
        foreach ($classMetadata->getAssociationMappings() as $fieldName => $mapping) {
            if ($mapping['type'] == ClassMetadataInfo::MANY_TO_MANY && $mapping['isOwningSide']) {
                $mappedTableName = $mapping['joinTable']['name'];
                $classMetadata->associationMappings[$fieldName]['joinTable']['name'] = $this->getPrefix($mapping['targetEntity'], $mappedTableName) . $mappedTableName;
            }
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @param string $tableName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPrefix(string $className, string $tableName): string
    {
        // get the namespaces from the class name
        // $className might be "App\Calendar\Entity\CalendarEntity"
        $nameSpaces = explode('\\', $className);
        $bundleName = isset($nameSpaces[1]) ? strtolower($nameSpaces[1]) : null;
 
        if (!$bundleName || !isset($this->config[$bundleName])) {
            return '';
        }
 
        $prefix = $this->config[$bundleName];
 
        // table is already prefixed with bundle name
        if (strpos($tableName, $prefix) === 0) {
            return '';
        }
 
        return $prefix;
    }
 
    /**
     * Returns an array of events this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSubscribedEvents() method.
    }
}
```

`

service.yaml : `

```
event.doctrine.table_prefix_subscriber:
    class: App\Event\TablePrefixEventListener
    arguments: ['%table_prefix%']
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

`table_prefix.yaml :`

```
parameters:
    table_prefix:
        event: TIP_
        User: TIP_
        family: API_
        SubFamily: API_
        Product: TIP_
        ProductSize: TIP_
        ProductStock: TIP_
```

`

I don't get any prefix. I've tried many options without any results
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners and event subscribers behaves little different.
You forgot to define, to which event you want to subscribe:

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class TablePrefixEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::loadClassMetadata
        ];
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks but non change by adding this code

Comment: can you tell me where goes the table_prefix.yaml, or if I can put the prefix in eventSubscriber class

Comment: Your *table_prefix.yaml* contains data defined by you. It's up to you how you going to store that data. You can load it from yaml or you can define it as class constant. If you want to load data from yaml, place that file in **./config/packages/table_prefix.yaml**. This file is automatically loaded by Symfony kernel(see: **./src/Kernel.php**). Next you define your service as you define it in original post. DI ensures that your Subscriber receive those data in constructor. Maybe that's your problem, you didn't obtain your yaml data in subscriber. **See edited post.**